# Accessing aggregate functions on another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, expression, aggregate

I am using QGIS where I have:

- Layer 1 STREETS : lines each of one representing a street (one line one street), with different fields, with a unique id called `"Name"` (string)
- Layer 2 STAKES : points, each representing a stake, with a unique id `"UID"` (numeric), and different fields, with one of them referring to the street along which it stays. This field is `"StreetLink"` and refers to the `"Name"` in layer 1. (a dropdown selection)

I just want to add a calculated field (`"NbStakes"`) in STREET (Layer 1) which counts the number of stakes present along each street.

I found some suggested ways, but did not succeed.

The best I found was with aggregate:

```
aggregate('Stakes', 'count', 'StreetLink')
```

I have a number, the same for all streets, and the total sum of stakes. Normal there is no condition linking the correct fields of the 2 layers.

I tried to add a kind of where clause (where the streetlink of table2 is the same as the current Street Name. But it failed. It just gave me zero everywhere

```
aggregate(
    'Stakes',
    'count',
    'Streetlink',
    attribute(@parent, "Streetlink") = "Name"
    )
```

Any suggestion on the correct syntax to use, or another way of doing this?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

`@parent` is the current feature in the `streets` layer.

```sql
aggregate(layer:= 'stakes',
          aggregate:= 'count',
          expression:= Streetlink,
          filter:= Streetlink = attribute(@parent, 'Name')
          )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. I completely misunderstood the @Parent meaning !